# Solids of Revolution around other functions.

Tags: calculus, transformation, volume

Recently I've been thinking about solids of revlution, and thought about an interesting experiment. Can you rotate functions around, for example, the line $f(x)=x$? And consequently, could you rotate a function around another entirely different function?

To rotate solids around the line $f(x)=x$, I thought you might have to make the "cylinders" go diagonally, but I can't think of how you would do that (distance formula?). I am thinking that there is probably an easier technique, perhaps using the "solids with known cross sections" method.

About the second part of my question, imagine "rotating" the rectangle formed by $\int_{-1}^12dx$ around the parabola $g(x)=-\frac12x^{2}-1$. Does this idea make any sense? I would imagine the result would be very convoluted and weird (maybe relates to linear transformations).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, one may form rotations about any axis - there is nothing special about one coordinate system or another.  But, how do you intend to define rotations about a non-linear axis?  What is the transformation?

Comment: @Dr.MV, I am not sure how I would define rotations about a non-linear axis. Perhaps a (very weird) möbius transformation of some type?

Comment: You can use some linear algebra (rotation matrices) or [Pappus's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) to do this. However, it's a really cool exercise to use cross-sections to find the volume when you rotate the region bounded by $y=x$ and $y=x^2$ about the line $y=x$. You have to be very careful to keep track of your variables.

Comment: Hi, not to seem like “spam”, but I think I have at least found some insight into your question. You can first have a point on the relation and/or functional axis and then draw its normal line in the direction of the other relation/function. Then make the line go in the other direction and be the same length from the point to the other function. Please visit my question to see this simplified! [Part of Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086916/on-surfaces-of-revolution-with-any-two-relations-in-bbb-r2-such-that-one-is)